# Compute $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{n\sin(x/n)}{1+x^4}dx$.

Tags: real-analysis

I try to apply dominated convergence theorem to compute the limit of following integral:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{n\sin(x/n)}{1+x^4}dx
$$

Note that let $y=x/n$, then
$$
 \frac{n^2\sin(y)}{1+n^4y^4}\le \frac{n^2}{1+n^4y^4}\le \frac{n^2}{2n^2y^2}=\frac{1}{2y^2}
$$

But $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2y^2}$ is not convergent... So I am stuck here...

Comment: Can you just use $|\sin t|\le |t|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $$0\leq x-\sin x\leq\frac{x^3}{6},\quad x\geq0,$$
we have
$$\left|\frac{n\sin(x/n)}{1+x^4}-\frac{x}{1+x^4}\right|
=\frac{n}{1+x^4}\left(\frac{x}{n}-\sin\frac{x}{n}\right)
\leq\frac{n}{1+x^4}\cdot\frac{x^3}{6n^3}
=\frac{1}{6n^2}\cdot\frac{x^3}{1+x^4}
\leq\frac{M}{6n^2},$$
where $M=\max\limits_{x\in[0,\infty)}\frac{x^3}{1+x^4}$.
This implies $\frac{n\sin(x/n)}{1+x^4}$ converges to $\frac{x}{1+x^4}$
on $[0,\infty)$ uniformly. For $n\in\mathbb N$ and $x\geq0$,
$$\left|\frac{n\sin(x/n)}{1+x^4}\right|\leq\frac{x}{1+x^4,}$$
this implies
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{n\sin(x/n)}{1+x^4}dx$$
is uniformly convergent with respect to $n$.

So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\frac{n\sin(x/n)}{1+x^4}dx
=\int_0^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\sin(x/n)}{1+x^4}dx\\
=\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{1+x^4}dx
=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Why $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\sin(x/n)=x$ but not $0\times \infty=0$? I remember we define $0\times \infty=0$ in real analysis. I know that $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(x)/x=1$... But why is not a contradiction?

Comment: @ 
H.Y Duan If $x=0$, it is nothing to say. If $x\neq0$, $$n\sin(x/n)=x\frac{\sin(x/n)}{x/n}\to x.$$

Comment: But $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(x/n)=0$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\sin(x/n)=\infty \times 0=0$, Why this is not true?

Comment: @ H.Y Duan Here is no real analysis, just advanced calculus ( In China, it is called Mathematical Analysis). I know , in real analysis, it is defined $0\times\infty=0$. Here  I didn't use "dominated convergence theorem". Although, using "dominated convergence theorem", this problem is even simple!

Comment: @ H.Y Duan You can refer the theorem of the following website: (Page598 theorem 16.2.5) https://www.doc88.com/p-6661801892025.html

Answer (score 3):

Without making the substitution you can use $g(x)=\frac x {1+x^{4}}$ as  a dominating integrable function. [$|\sin t|\le t$ for all $t>0$].

Answer (score 3):

*For the pleasure of computing an interesting integral.*

$$I=\int\frac{n \sin \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{x^4+1}\,dx=\int \frac{n^2 \sin (t)}{n^4 t^4+1}\,dt=\int \frac{n^2 \sin (t)}{n^4 \prod_{k=1}^4 (t-r_k)}\,dt$$ where
$$r_{1,2}=\pm\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2} n}\qquad \text{and}\qquad r_{3,4}=\pm\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2} n}$$

Partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{n^2 }{n^4 \prod_{k=1}^4 (t-r_k)}=\frac 1 {n^2} \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac {A_k}{t-r_k}$$ and then four integrals
$$J_k=\int_0^\infty \frac {\sin(t)}{t-r_k}\,dt$$ Obvious changes of variable and expansion of the sine function leads to
$$J_k=\frac{1}{2} (2 \text{Si}(r_k)+\pi ) \cos (r_k)-\text{Ci}(-r_k) \sin (r_k)$$

Back to $x$ and the bounds, using series
$$K=\int_0^\infty\frac{n \sin \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{x^4+1}\,dx=\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{6 \log (n)-6 \gamma +11}{36 n^2}-\frac{\pi}{480 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$ which is a quite good approximation even for small values of $n$